# AES Encryption with SQL then Decrypt with Javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, encryption

I am trying to get basic encryption on my database for my app and i am having trouble with decrypting it in my app.

I have managed to get specific data to be encrypted with AES.

```
AES_ENCRYPT(data, '9027382883960882');
```

This returns me data like this: ÷çôpFx4Ûk`©ùþ§­ß-ð?±AGXxPkoË

The data from the database then gets put on a page as JSON data.
We then get the data through a XMLHTTP request on the app.

We then have the encrypted data on the app but then i need to deccrypt it.

I dont know how we can do this in a good way because when we use a plug-in like [Aes-js](https://github.com/ricmoo/aes-js).

We first have to change the encrypted data to Hexdecimal or Bytes and that is not possible because the data has random signs in it.

Do you guys have any idea how we can do this or maybe a push in the right direction.

Comment: Do you really want to expose the key to the outside world?

Comment: The data is not super sensitive and i am planning to secure the source code and server soo the keys hardcoded wont be much of a problem

Comment: You are going to leak the key anyway so just do the decryption server side. By the way AES is supported by default by all major browser https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto#Browser_compatibility

Comment: The data returned to you *consists of random looking bytes* because that's what ciphertext is. The problem you are facing is that you *try and view it as a string*. Instead, you should convert it to base 64 or indeed hexadecimals in case you need text. Otherwise you can directly decrypt it *without first converting it to text*.